# Let $\omega_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Prove $1+\omega_n+\omega^2_n+\cdots+\omega^{n-1}_n=0.$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

> Let $\omega_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Prove $1+\omega_n+\omega^2_n+\cdots+\omega^{n-1}_n=0.$

Note: I tried using mathematical induction and some basic trig identities but I can't seem to crack this one. Any hints???

Comment: think of it as a geometric sum

Comment: Sum of a geometric series?

Comment: use the fact that the points $\omega_n^k$  for $k=0,1,2,,n-1$ are vertex of a regular polygon of $N$ sides.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1+\omega_n+\omega_n^2+\cdots+\omega_n^{n-1} = \frac{1-\omega_n^n}{1-\omega_n}=\frac{1-e^{2\pi i}}{1-\omega_n}=\frac{1-1}{1-\omega_n}=0.$$

Comment: Took me a while, but I did it and it was this way!

Comment: nth partial sum of a geometric series on LHS of course.

Comment: Glad you were able to work it out!

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:** Notice that $\omega_n^n=1$ so $\omega_n$ is a root of $x^n-1$. Also,
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$$
Thus, since $\omega_n-1\ne 0$, you can conclude that...

Answer (score 6):

Note that

$\omega_n = e^{2\pi i / n} \tag 1$

satisfies

$\omega_n^n - 1 = (e^{2\pi i / n})^n - 1$
$= e^{2 \pi n i / n} - 1 = e^{2 \pi i} - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0; \tag 2$

we also have the well-known identity

$\omega_n^n - 1 = (\omega_n - 1)(1 + \omega_n + \omega_n^2 + \ldots + \omega_n^{n - 1})$
$= (\omega_n - 1) \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} \omega_n^k; \tag 3$

combining (2) and (3) yields

$(\omega_n - 1)(1 + \omega_n + \omega_n^2 + \ldots + \omega_n^{n - 1})$
$= (\omega_n - 1) \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} \omega_n^k = 0, \tag 4$

and since

$\omega_n \ne 1, \tag 5$

we have

$\omega_n - 1 \ne 0; \tag 6$

now dividing (4) through by $\omega_n - 1$ yields

$1 + \omega_n + \omega_n^2 + \ldots + \omega_n^{n - 1} =  \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} \omega_n^k = 0, \tag 7$

the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! What is the name of the identity in line (3)?

Comment: @whitenoise:  I don't know that it has a name but it pops up everywhere.  A more general case is $a^n - b^n = (a - b) \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} a^k b^{n - k - 1}$